# list index out of range cuando ya tengo una lista creada y la puedo imprimir

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista

```
e=[]
entrada=input("Entrada de dades: ")
dades1=entrada.split("*")
for cad in dades1:
    e=cad.split()
    nom=e[0]
    nTaron=e[2]
    nPeixos=e[4]
    nBlat=e[6]
```

El caso es que quiero asignar esas variables a lo que se obtiene del array pero me salta el error de list index out of range. La lista la puedo imprimir (e) pero no puedo guardarme los valores en una variable.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuántos elementos tiene la lista `e`? (puedes averiguarlo con `len(e)`)

Comment: Si imprimo len(e) me sale que es 0. En teoria tendria que ser 11 ya que es lo que le paso por el input y hasta donde yo se con el split se te añaden directamente a una lista

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar cómo sería un ejemplo del input que le das al programa?

Comment: sid t 53 p 12 t 45 b 21 t 20 *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en una de las iteraciones del bucle `for` (la última) no tienes datos que procesar.

En efecto, si le entrada que le das al `input()` es (como has indicado en un comentario) la línea `p sid t 53 p 12 t 45 b 21 t 20 *`, ya que lo primero que haces es un `.split("*")` eso te va a generar una lista con dos elmentos:

```
# Valor de dades1=
['sid t 53 p 12 t 45 b 21 t 20 ', '']
```

La primera vez que iteras por esa lista no hay problema. `cad` toma el valor `"sid t 53 p 12 t 45 b 21 t 20 "` y todo va bien. Pero en la siguiente iteración `cad` toma el valor `""` (cadena vacía), por lo que el `split()` produce en `e` una lista vacía, y de ahí el error.

Una forma sencilla de evitarlo es saltarte los elementos que no tengan la longitud esperada:

```
entrada=input("Entrada de dades: ")
dades1=entrada.split("*")
for cad in dades1:
    e=cad.split()
    if len(e)<6:
       continue
    nom=e[0]
    nTaron=e[2]
    nPeixos=e[4]
    nBlat=e[6]
```

La sentencia `continue` hace que abandone esa iteración del bucle y pase a la siguiente. O quizás quieras hacer un `break` (saldría del bucle), o quizás no iterar, sino trabajar tan solo con `dades1[0]`. Esto ya depende de tu caso de uso.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya funciona! :) Un saludo compañero!